# Color schemes from Mathematica in MatLab

Tags: matlab, colors, wolfram-mathematica, color-scheme

I'm using `MatLab` for plotting my data and now I'm interested in getting [color schemes from `Mathematica`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html), because the ones in `MatLab` are actually not the best.

Is there any way to import them in `MatLab`?

If not, is there a way to get similar color schemes like the *DarkRainbow* or the *Rainbow* in `MatLab`? (I hate the *jet* in `MatLab` since one is not able to see the yellow lines)

Comment: matlab colormaps are Nx3 arrays, where each column represents an R G and B value. If you are able to export a colourmap from Mathematica in such a format, then you can specify the colormap directly.

Answer (score 5):

Create an appropriate table in Mathematica:

```
mint = Table[List @@ ColorData["MintColors"][x], {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];
```

Test in MATLAB using [MATLink](http://matlink.org/)

```
<< MATLink`

OpenMATLAB[]

MSet["mint", mint]

MEvaluate[
 "figure
 surf(peaks)
 colormap(mint)
 "
]
```

[image]

Export to a `.mat` file in case you don't have MATLink:

```
Export["mint" -> mint, {"MAT", "LabeledData"}]
```